# What is the convention for keeping old code for reference?

Tags: java, svn

I have a fairly new small team project with a new team and we have tried a few different approaches and had a few significant iterations in design.

We have some classes laying around that should not be used and a few classes that have such messes as ClassStuff and ClassStuffImproved. We have SVN but I don't think nuking all the junk and making people dig manually in the history is productive. Some things may need to be re implemented properly and the previous poor implementation would provide a reference. I do however want to break anything that depends on junk. I also want the project to build even if these junk files are broken.

Is there a folder convention? Should i put all nuked content in a textfile so at least its easily searchable when someone wonders where a class went?

What is the typical convention here?

Comment: There is no convention. Use what you see fit. For example, create an `attic` directory, which has the normal structure of a source code root.

Comment: Perhaps create a branch, and then reduce the trunk to functional/used code.  Refer to the branch to reimplement classes as needed.

Comment: If the class should not be used (or contains garbage), I think removing it from the trunk expeditiously is the best thing you can do. Using a branch/tag also seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've kept SVN history logs in place by using TortoiseSVN's Repository Browser. If you have a recent SVN server, operations like "Move to", "Copy to" and "Rename" will keep history logs to the original. Be sure to update all checkouts after these kind of changes (else local changes will have a hard time merging with the new server reality).

Files you no longer use can be moved to a "museum" or "attic" branch (and try to keep the original directory structure in there).

Apache projects have been changing package names to indicate new versions that more or less break with previous versions (e.g. compare commons-lang [2.6](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/index.html) with [3.2](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.2.1/index.html)). In SVN you can do this by simply renaming a directory in the trunk. I find it a good convention: all code that depends on the old version breaks but is easily updated by adding one character to the import statements (and ofcourse you verify the new version works as expected by reading the updated Apidocs).

Re-implementing junk is, in my experience, harder than it looks at first glance. I use the `@Deprecated` annotation at class-level at first for classes that need to be replaced. Your IDE will clearly show where deprecated code is used and the compiler will show warnings. Create the re-implementation in a package 'version 2'. Then you can update like you would update from commons-lang version 2 to commons-lang version 3. Once this is all done, delete the deprecated classes (or package). 

Be careful when deleting deprecated classes though: the last time I tried deleting deprecated classes, I found a dependency on the deprecated classes in one little and old, but crucial and heavily tested, program and had to keep the deprecated classes in place to maintain backwards compatability.

Comment: Thank you. This seems a sensible solution and some helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a convention, in my projects I just copy it into a new version with a name like:

```
MyClass2.java
```

This way I won't get into trouble when I'm importing and old version of a source file. And I also comment the whole contents of `MyClass.java` with `/* ... */`. After some reasonable amount of time I drop the old `MyClass` version and leave `MyClass2` in the project. I'm leaving it as `MyClass2`, so that it states that it this file has history and it's a more advanced version of my class, so brings a little fun into the process.

I've never seen anyone doing this, but the practice seems quite intuitive.